# Distributing Frontend Assets with Plugins

Tags: plugin-development, css, admin-css

I'd like to distribute some custom style sheets (`.css`) and javascript files (`.js`) with my plugin.  Is there a *right* way to do this in Wordpress?  I can think of a number of different ways to do this, but I'd prefer to use one that's Wordpress recommended, or a defacto time and true standard.  Specifically

1. Where should I place my CSS/JS files?  In `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/css/etc.css`? Somewhere else?
2. How should I generate URLs to these assets in my plugin?  `<?php site_url() . '/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/css/etc.css ?>`  Is it safe to hardcode `wp-content/plugin`, or is there a better function/functions to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - it's up to you and subject to opinion, so not best suited to WPSE.

2 - Never hardcode paths.  WP has whole range of functions for finding file paths and URLS.  `plugins_url()` will get you the full URL to the plugins directory, handling whether you are using http or https and canonicalising the domain name for you.  It will take parameters for a file relative to your plugin's directory by using PHP's magic `__FILE__` constant too: `plugins_url( 'images/plugin_icon.png', __FILE__ )` for example.

Similarly, `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` within a plugin file will get the full system file path to the file.

Comment: in addition of this, I recommand to use the function [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)